# arm neon compare operations generate negative one

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

I am trying the following assembly code:

```
vclt.f32 q9,q0,#0
vst1.i32 q9,[r2:128]
```

But if the condition is true, the corresponding element in q9 is set to negative one instead of positive one.

What can I do to get a positive one ?

Comment: It produces all 1 bits, which is indeed -1 if you interpret it as 2's complement signed. If you need just a single 1 bit, how about you use bitwise `AND`.

Comment: So it is normal result ? I thought it is a kind of error. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's normal. This is more useful for masking operations, and you can easily get the one you want from it too.

Comment: @PaulR: I'd be inclined to close that one as a duplicate of this.  This one has more practical answers talking about what you can do with the -1, since the question what "how do I work with this", rather than "why?".  Especially Notlikethat's answer has actual instruction names (vs. the hand-waving in my answer :P)

Comment: @PeterCordes: yes, I think you're right - I've applied the dupe-hammer to the older question now, and retracted the close-vote on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal for vector compare instructions, so you can use the compare result as a mask with AND or XOR instructions, or various other use-cases.

You usually don't need a +1.  If you want to count the number of elements that match, for example, just use a subtract instruction to subtract 0 or -1 from a vector accumulator.

---

To get an integer +1, you could subtract it from 0, or right-shift by element-size -1.  (e.g. logical right-shift by 31 to leave just the low bit 0 or 1, and the rest of the bits all-zero).  You could also AND with a vector of +1s that you created earlier.

I don't know which of these would be best for ARM, or if that would depend on the microarchitecture.  (I really only know SIMD for x86 SSE/AVX.)  I'm sure NEON can do at least one of the options I described, though.

Comment: It's inconvenient that conditionals in C/C++ return `1` but the SIMD conditions return `-1`. I made an app where the user could select the vector size in real-time (just to show the performance with each). E.g. for float the size could be `1,4,8`.  I used Agner's VCL. But I had to make special templates for vector size = 1 (i.e. scalars). I guess scalar code and vector code need to be different anyway for comparing performance fairly.

Answer (score 4):

There's not a lot of conditional stuff in NEON, but what there is is really only workable with bitwise, rather than Boolean, logic - see e.g. `vbsl`.

If you have horrible memories of BASIC and really hate bitwise truth values, then the trivial way to convert the mask to a Boolean is to just take the top bit of each element:

```
vshr.u32 q9, q9, #31
```

Although negation, whilst arguably less clear to read at a glance, could be microscopically better performance-wise in some cases:

```
vneg.s32 q9, q9
```

(from a browse through microarchitectural timings, both operations are pretty much identical, but some theoretical advantages of `vneg` over `vshr` are that it consumes its inputs later on Cortex-A8, and can issue down both ASIMD pipes of Cortex-A57/A72)

Either way, as said at the top, this only really makes sense for storing the result back to memory to be looked at by non-vectorised code.

Comment: Where is microarchitectural info documented?  Is there anything for ARM like [Agner Fog's x86 microarch guide and instruction timings](http://agner.org/optimize/), where timings are listed in an easy-to-flip-through format?  A quick google found [this official ARM page](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0165b/I1028171.html), but I've always found ARM's official web-site hard to navigate, esp. for comparing something between different ARM versions.  (Navigating down the same tree from a different top-level ARM chip is ridiculous.)

Comment: @Peter Older cores (up to Cortex-A9) give general cycle timings in their TRMs as you found, the newest ones are starting to get publicly released [optimisation guides](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.uan0016a/index.html); sadly there is a bit of a gap in the middle. The only bit of Agner-style reverse-engineering I've come across is [this partial analysis of Cortex-A7](http://hardwarebug.org/2014/05/15/cortex-a7-instruction-cycle-timings/).